# Can I use a Shimano RD-M735 rear derailleur with road shifters like the SL-6400 (7s) or the SL-6401 (8s)?

Tags: shimano, compatibility

I'd like to set up an old school touring/rando bike.
Do Shimano road and mountain bike components of that era (7 and 8 speed) share the same cable pull ratio? I know the RD-M735 is 7 speed, using it as an 8 speed derailleur shouldn't be an issue. But I'm not sure when it comes to shifter compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work perfectly. Every pre-10-speed Shimano MTB rear derailleur will index with every road shifter prior (chronologically) to the beginning of 11-speed road, except for 7400/7410 Dura Ace.

Comment: fantastic, thank you